# SwiftUI navigation link back button working in preview but not in simulator or device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, navigationview

Im trying to use a simple navigation view, with a navigation link to a different view. When running the app and the navigation link is pressed it takes me to the new view.

However when I'm on a simulator or device the back button dose not work, whereas on the preview it works fine.

Any ideas what the problem may be?

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Detail View")) {
                    Text("Hello World")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("SwiftUI")
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}
```

I think the problem may be caused by the fact that the HomeView is part of a tabView. The following code is from AppView.swift which is what is run when the app is run (You can see the code for that at the very bottom).

I think this is the problem because when the code bellow is commented out the app works fine.

```
HomeView()
.tabItem {
Image(systemName: "house.fill")
Text("Home")
}
.onTapGesture {
self.selectedTab = 2
}
.tag(2)
```

```
@main
struct Skate_AppApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            HomeView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried your code everything seems perfect to me! try to clean your project and rebuild.

Comment: I cleaned the build folder and rebuilt but unfortunately the problem is still there.

Comment: Did you try to create a new project? and which ios version are you using?

Comment: Im using IOS 14.2. When I create a new project it works. Do you have an idea why this might be? I don't want to keep creating new projects every time this happens, especially as the project grows.

Comment: if you can upload your project to github and post the link i will try to figure out what is going on with it. yes i got what you mean, those last days i was working on a project and i saw that swiftui is acting wired the code is right however i keep getting errors, when i undo the changes i see that it works and it's the same code loool, don't worry just create new project and work with it you won't face the problem again.

Comment: I think I may have found the cause of the problem but not the fix, I edited the question.

Comment: okay so when you lunch your app, your intial view is the tab view, i'll see if i find something i'll post an answer let me create your code first and run it and i'll see

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your code I can tell that the problem is in `onTapGesture`, and I presume from `self.selectedTab = 2` that you want to get which tab the user has selected.

Let's refactor your code a little bit with the same concept.

Solution: Delete `onTapGesture` and add `onAppear`.

```
    TabView {
        
        HomeView().tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                Text("Home")
        }.onAppear{
            self.selectedTab = 2
        }.tag(2)
        
        AnotherView().tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "car.fill")
                Text("Login View")
        }.onAppear{
            self.selectedTab = 3
        }.tag(3)
        
    }
```

By this whenever a view appears, it means that the user has selected it, `onAppear` will be called, and your variable `selectedTab` will be changed. I hope this answer your question.